# How to sort this pivot table from start of the month to the end of the month

Tags: excel, vba

I have the pivot table pasted below. As you can see the table's dates are out of order for some reason, I tried using the autosort method but it still was generating out of order.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYHbJ.png)

**

```
Sub editPT2()
'
' From the model start date get the month and year
mm = Month(Range("ModelStartDate"))
yr = Year(Range("ModelStartDate"))

' Using the model start month & year, get the next month. May require getting the next year if current month is december
If mm = 12 Then
    mm = 1
    yr = yr + 1
Else
    mm = mm + 1
End If

' Create new start & end dates (Always the first of the month)
myStartDate = DateSerial(yr, mm, 1)
myEndDate = DateSerial(yr, mm, 31)

' Edit pivot table so that it starts on the first of the next month
For Each pt In Worksheets("Before 20th - PREI Schedule Rep").PivotTables
    pt.PivotFields("Date").ClearAllFilters
'    pt.PivotFields("Date").DataRange.Cells(1).Ungroup
    pt.PivotFields("Date").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlDateBetween, _
        Value1:=myStartDate, Value2:=myEndDate
'    pt.PivotFields("Date").DataRange.Cells(1).Group , _
'        by:=7, Start:=myStartDate, Periods:=Array(False, False, False, True, False, False, False)
Next pt
End Sub
```

**